# Lunar surface illumination

Tags: the-moon

I am trying to determine the lunar surface near or far side daytime illumination levels in Lux or foot-candles but there seems to be no directly measured values available. I did find this information on the levels as measured from earth, so it should be possible to work backwards to arrive at those values I presume. My math is very rusty indeed though, so thought I'd put the question to some experts.
How bright is moonlight?
https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/58/1/1.31/2938119

Comment: This is certainly on-topic here but it is possible that it would receive more helpful results in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) where there are many users familliar with how to find measured data on the Moon.

Comment: I see [you've now done so](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43519/12102), but I realize that I should have said something about deleting this here first. In Stack Exchange cross-posting the same question in multiple sites is strongly discouraged, one reason is that it leads to answer fragmentation. It's a good idea to delete one of these instances. Thanks!